# oAuth авторизация mail.ru

Tags: oauth2, mail.ru

Вопрос может не сильно подходит для стека, но может быть кто сталкивался.

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать сайт http://api.mail.ru/sites/my/add/, но зайти на эту страницу не могу постоянно редиректит на страницу https://my.mail.ru/my/welcome?back_after_reg=http://api.mail.ru/sites/my/add/

Использую vpn (OPERA, ZenMate).

Как можно попасть на страницу добавления сайта?